# htaccess rewrite to add fragment

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an index page `index.php` with shows the right section depending on the fragment:

Are valid:

```
/index.php
/index.php#About
/index.php#Contact
/index.php#404error
...
```

by defining `DirectoryIndex index.php` I made sure request like /#About are understood weel, but still I'd like to rewrite url to manage nice error display

I tried doing

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php#404error
```

but that is not good the the url not being rewritten makes that the webpage doesn't have access to the fragment ...

I also tried using RewriteRule

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /404 /index.php#404 [R=301,L]
```

How can I achieve such a behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get fragment in browser you will have to use full redirect like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/index.php#404error
```

---

**EDIT:** To keep protocol same use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php#404error [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Any idea how to make it addapt to protocol (http/https) ?

Comment: +1 for updated answer, still it only does the trick for error 404, other errors (403...) are not covered ...

Comment: Yes that's right things will get really tricky for 403, 401 etc. Also question didn't have any hint that you want to handle 403 also. If you open a new question you might get some other alternatives from experts here.